# jquery ajax form submit not working with codeigniter but working otherwise

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to submit a form using jquery ajax without codeigniter just to understand how ajax works. It worked fine but now I want to do it in codeigniter (since I am developing my application in CI). It's not inserting the values in the database. I do not know how to check where the problem is

This is my form in view :-

```
<form name="article_form" method="POST" action="">
 <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title for your article" />
 <br>
 <textarea rows="12" name="body" placeholder="Tell your story"></textarea>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_article" id="submit_article" value="Post" />
</form>
```

This is my jquery ajax script :-

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        $('#submit_article').click(function(){

            var article_title = document.getElementById("title").value;
            var article_body = document.getElementById("body").value;

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url()."main/submit_article";?>',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'title='+article_title + '&body='+article_body,
                success: function(output_string){
                    $('#result_table').append(output_string);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Main is the controller and this the function submit_article :-

```
public function submit_article()
{
        $article_title = $this->input->post('title');
        $article_body = $this->input->post('body');

    $this->load->model("model_articles");

    if($this->model_articles->article_submit($article_title, $article_body))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This loads the model - model_articles and passes two value namely $article_title and $article_body to the function article_submit(). This is the function in the model that has to insert the values into the database :-

```
public function article_submit($article_title, $article_body)
    {
        $article_data = array(
            'title' => $article_title,
            'body' => $article_body
            );

        $query_insert_article = $this->db->insert('articles', $article_data);
        if($query_insert_article)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure no records are being entered in your DB? What happens if you try `var_dump($article_title, $article_body);` in your controller?

Comment: I get this bool(false) bool(false)

Comment: hi, 0, 0 are being stored in database. This means that the insert function ios working. I think the value is not reaching the controller from the view. Is there any way to the check this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your controller function and ajax to
try this one

```
    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $('#submit_article').click(function(){

        var article_title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
       var article_body = $('textarea[name="body"]').val();


        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url()."main/submit_article";?>/'+article_title+'/'+article_body ,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  $('#form_id').serialize(),/*edit form_id*/
            success: function(output_string){
                $('#result_table').append(output_string);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this one is yours controller

```
  public function submit_article($article_title,$article_body )
  {


$this->load->model("model_articles");

if($this->model_articles->article_submit($article_title, $article_body))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}

hope it will sovle .....

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your JavaScript to this:

```
$('#submit_article').click(function(e) {

    var article_title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
    var article_body = $('textarea[name="body"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/submit_article',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'title=' + article_title + '&body=' + article_body,
        success: function(output_string) {
            $('#result_table').append(output_string);
        }
    });

    // Add this if you want to prevent the normal form from sending:
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i added this but no luck, I also made a change to input tag by adding id="title" and id="body". It does'nt work. when I run the controller with pre-assigned values for $article_title and $article_body it stores the value in the database. But when I submit the form with values nothing happens. I guess there is something weong with the veiw and jquery ajax code